# How to scroll images horizontally on a blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to scroll the images horizontally with its title and description, I had done using picture scroll view but it shows only title that too at the bottom of the screen but i want to display it at the top and with the title i want to display its description also, please help.
And another option i had tried using the interface scrollchangelistener by using that i displayed the images with its title and description on the top of the screen but it scrolls in vertical direction i am unable to do it in horizontal. Please help i am in great difficulty since last few days, Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Use `HorizontalFieldManager` and add the contents in it 
It will work 
Use `Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL` as argument in it

eg:

```
HorizontalFieldManager hfm=new HorizontalFieldManager(Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);
```

Answer (score -1):

This BlackBerry support forum thread will help you, in addition to the [PictureScrollField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/extension/component/PictureScrollField.html) documentation.

[how to show images in horizontal scroll field in blackberr](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Curve/how-to-show-images-in-horizontal-scroll-field-in-blackberr/td-p/1669443)

Comment: This i had used and its working perfectly as i wanted but i want to display the image title and its description on the top of the image but its not possible.